# How do I disable a select option based on another select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been wondering if I can disable a select option based on the value length of another select option.

```js
var start = 2010;
var end = 2030;
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idTahunBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

var start = 1;
var end = 12;
var options = "";
for (var month = start; month <= end; month++) {
  options += "<option>" + month + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

var start = 2010;
var end = 2030;
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idTahunBerlakuS").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

var start = 1;
var end = 12;
var options = "";
for (var month = start; month <= end; month++) {
  options += "<option>" + month + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlakuS").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

$('#idBtnSimpanSimpan').click(
  function() {
    if ($('#idPenerbit').val().length == 0 ||
      $('#idtrainingName').val().length == 0) {
      alert("ISI SEMUA FORM TERLEBIH DAHULU");
    } else {
      debugger;
      var vDatasertifikasi = $('#idFrmAddSertifikasi')
        .serialize();
      alert(vDatasertifikasi);
      debugger;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/savesertifikasi',
        type: 'POST',
        data: vDatasertifikasi,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(model) {
          debugger;
          if (model.status == "berhasil") {
            alert("Data berhasil disimpan");
            $('#idMdlNewSertifikasi').modal('hide');

            /* redirecting to home of barang */
            debugger;

          } else {
            alert("Data salah");
          }
        },
        error: function(model) {
          debugger;
        }
      });
    }
  });

$(".clSelectKiri").change(function() {
  if ($('#idTahunBerlaku').val().length == 0 &&
    $('#idBulanBerlaku').val().length == 0) {
    $(".clTgglKanan").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
    $(".clTgglKanan").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="idFrmAddSertifikasi" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- LEVEL 1 / KIRI -->
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="SertifikasiName" class="control-label">Nama
              Sertifikasi<sup>*</sup>
            </label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control clborderbiru" maxlength="50" id="idtrainingName" name="certificate_name" placeholder="" title="MAKS. KARAKTER 50">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="schoolName" class="control-label">Berlaku
              Mulai</label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clborderbiru clSelectKiri" id="idBulanBerlaku" name="valid_start_month">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Bulan -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clborderbiru clSelectKiri" id="idTahunBerlaku" name="valid_start_year">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Tahun -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- LEVEL 2 / KANAN -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="organizer" class="control-label">Penerbit<sup>*</sup></label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control clborderbiru" id="idPenerbit" name="publisher" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="schoolName" class="control-label">Berlaku
              Sampai</label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clTgglKanan clborderbiru" id="idBulanBerlakuS" name="until_month">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Bulan -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clTgglKanan clborderbiru" id="idTahunBerlakuS" name="until_year">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Tahun -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="notes" class="control-label">Catatan</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <textarea class="form-control clborderbiru" id="idCatatan" rows="6" name="notes"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-offset-10">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn clBtnMdl">Batal</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn clBtnMdl" id="idBtnSimpanSimpan">Simpan</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I select a value in the .clSelectKiri value length == 0 I want the .clTgglKanan to be disabled. And there's a hidden option, is that affecting it?
This is the code I've been working, but it isn't working. Does anyone has any idea why?

Comment: I dont see `value == 0` of  the .clSelectKiri element.

Comment: `$(".clTgglKanan option").attr("disabled", "disabled");` you cant disabled the entire select element but you can disabled the options. user wont be able to select any option

Comment: Your options have no values. Test for `.text` or do like `if(selectElement.selectedIndex === index){ otherSelect.selectedIndex = otherIndex; }`

Comment: oops sorry what i meant is value length. If the .clSelectKiri has the value length of 0 it'd be disabled. if the .clSelectKiri has value length more than 0 .clTgglKanan would be able.

Comment: Like @StackSlave, your options don't have values.  Are you wanting to test for the length of the text of the options instead ?

Comment: A word of advice to help contributors so they can help you: In future please keep your example to as minimal as possible as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` statement that disables the lower two `select` elements you just need to change `.val().length == 0` to `.val` and that will disable them when the top two are selected.

```js
var start = 2010;
var end = 2030;
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idTahunBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

var start = 1;
var end = 12;
var options = "";
for (var month = start; month <= end; month++) {
  options += "<option>" + month + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

var start = 2010;
var end = 2030;
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idTahunBerlakuS").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

var start = 1;
var end = 12;
var options = "";
for (var month = start; month <= end; month++) {
  options += "<option>" + month + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlakuS").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", options);

$('#idBtnSimpanSimpan').click(
  function() {
    if ($('#idPenerbit').val().length == 0 ||
      $('#idtrainingName').val().length == 0) {
      alert("ISI SEMUA FORM TERLEBIH DAHULU");
    } else {
      debugger;
      var vDatasertifikasi = $('#idFrmAddSertifikasi')
        .serialize();
      alert(vDatasertifikasi);
      debugger;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/savesertifikasi',
        type: 'POST',
        data: vDatasertifikasi,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(model) {
          debugger;
          if (model.status == "berhasil") {
            alert("Data berhasil disimpan");
            $('#idMdlNewSertifikasi').modal('hide');

            /* redirecting to home of barang */
            debugger;

          } else {
            alert("Data salah");
          }
        },
        error: function(model) {
          debugger;
        }
      });
    }
  });

$(".clSelectKiri").change(function() {
  if ($('#idTahunBerlaku').val() && $('#idBulanBerlaku').val()) {
    $(".clTgglKanan").attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $(".clTgglKanan").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="idFrmAddSertifikasi" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- LEVEL 1 / KIRI -->
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="SertifikasiName" class="control-label">Nama
              Sertifikasi<sup>*</sup>
            </label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control clborderbiru" maxlength="50" id="idtrainingName" name="certificate_name" placeholder="" title="MAKS. KARAKTER 50">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="schoolName" class="control-label">Berlaku
              Mulai</label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clborderbiru clSelectKiri" id="idBulanBerlaku" name="valid_start_month">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Bulan -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clborderbiru clSelectKiri" id="idTahunBerlaku" name="valid_start_year">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Tahun -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- LEVEL 2 / KANAN -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label for="organizer" class="control-label">Penerbit<sup>*</sup></label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control clborderbiru" id="idPenerbit" name="publisher" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <label for="schoolName" class="control-label">Berlaku
              Sampai</label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clTgglKanan clborderbiru" id="idBulanBerlakuS" name="until_month">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Bulan -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control clTgglKanan clborderbiru" id="idTahunBerlakuS" name="until_year">
                      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Pilih
                        Tahun -</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="notes" class="control-label">Catatan</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <textarea class="form-control clborderbiru" id="idCatatan" rows="6" name="notes"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-offset-10">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn clBtnMdl">Batal</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn clBtnMdl" id="idBtnSimpanSimpan">Simpan</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I wanted it to be reversed than what you've done. But i've solved it with your way just changing the if statement!
Thankyou So Much!

Comment: @PiPio Oh OK. So when the page loads you want the lower two selects to start off disabled and then only be enabled when the first two have been selected?

Comment: @PiPio I've just edited my answer. Please tell me if it's now doing what you want.